# HTTP.put method in dart

Tags: http, dart, flutter, put

I have been trying to send a **http put** request through flutter framework using the dart http package.
Here is my json String

```
var jsonMap = {

  'status': '1',
    'time': new DateTime.now().toIso8601String(),
    'teamMemId': '7',
    'empId': "953280086v",
    'comId': 2.toString(),
    'description': "j new attendence",
    'effDate': date.toIso8601String()


};
```

and the http request method

```
String jsonStr = jsonEncode(jsonMap);
print(jsonMap);
http.put(Uri.encodeFull(url), body: jsonStr , headers: { "Accept" : "application/json"}).then((result) {
  print(result.statusCode);
  print(result.body);
});
```

The error is that node.js file does not capture the json string, it just shows an empty object. However, when I tested with the postman it works well.

Comment: What is the printed `result.statusCode` and `result.body`?

Comment: result.status code => 400

Comment: result.body => status is required . in the node.js request there is nothin in the body

Comment: That means the server expects a different request, but there is no way we can know what the server expects (what "status is required" could mean).

Comment: status is required means i have not provided value for the **status** in the above json sting i submitted

Comment: You could try sending `jsonMap` instead of `jsonStr` but I'm not sure that will help.

Comment: i already tried to send jsonMap but it did not work, thinks for your help

Comment: I guess you need to figure out what the difference is between the request made from postman and from Dart (what arrives on the server).

Comment: Same request you can sed from any rest API client from browser abd check is the server is getting same data.

Answer (score 6):

try change in the headers "Accept" to `headers: { "Content-Type" : "application/json"}`